# Java android realm check if objects is exist (check two )

Tags: java, android, realm

This is my object :

```
public class ObjectsInGroupRealm extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String groupName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

And when I create a new object I want to check if object is exist this same name and this same groupName . A object name could be in few groups. This is my code how I save a objects :

```
 public static void saveObjectsInGroup(ArrayList<String> objects, String groupName , Realm realm){

        for(String object : objects){

            ObjectsInGroupRealm objectsInGroupRealm = new ObjectsInGroupRealm();
            Long key;
            try {
                key = (Long) realm.where(ObjectsInGroupRealm.class).max("id") + 1;
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                key = 0L; // when there is no object in the database yet
            }

            objectsInGroupRealm.setId(key);
            objectsInGroupRealm.setName(object);
            objectsInGroupRealm.setGroupName(groupName);
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealm(objectsInGroupRealm);
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @GhostCat I want to check if is exist objects which groupName and name which i have, When is not exist I want to save this objects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the easiest way is doing a query and checking if the returned Object is null:

```
ObjectsInGroupRealm object = realm.where(ObjectsInGroupRealm.class)
    .equalTo("name", name)
    .equalTo("groupName", groupName)
    .findFirst();
 if(object == null){
     //add new object
 } else {
     //handle object already existing
 }
```

Comment: when I do this always a object is save

Comment: So using my code you end up with duplicate objects?